# IBM Websphere MQ C# app - Reconnect after MQRC_Q_MGR_NOT_AVAILABLE

Tags: c#, ibm-mq, mq

I'm having the same issue as in post [Getting error reason code 2059 on MQ client (C#) when reconnecting to QueueManager after awhile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973283/getting-error-reason-code-2059-on-mq-client-c-when-reconnecting-to-queuemanag).

It's an intermitent problem. A server application which connects and disconnects from MQ using polling, sometimes receive a MQRC_Q_MGR_NOT_AVAILABLE. Even creating new connections at each poll, the application didn't recover automatically. It's a C# app, using standard MQ .NET Libraries.

After restarting the service, it works normally. Usually the problem happens once a week and a half.

For each poll, the new connection is created using:

```
manager = new IBM.WMQ.MQQueueManager(config.QueueManagerName);
```

The IBM.WMQ.MQQueueManager manager instance is stored in a private variable, and after the operations are done, the connection is closed, calling

```
 manager.Disconnect();
 manager.Close();
```

Am I missing something?

I tried to simulate the problem, and even after 100.000 connections and disconnections it didn't happens :-(

Any guesses?

Answer (score 0):

Try nullifying the manager object after calling Disconnect. Something like

```
manager.Disconnect();
manager = null;
```

Comment: Shashi, I didn't explicit set it to null, but, in the next reconnection, manager will be set to a new instance of MQQueueManager, what will make the old reference be garbage collected.

Comment: I also noted that the IBM classes don't implement IDisposable. I have no idea of how they manage their handles internally.

Answer (score 0):

I worked with IBM for a while in this bug, and no solution was found. Everyone agreed that there was a problem, but their suggestion was to first of all upgrade everything to newer version of Websphere MQ which in my scenario would take ages due to internal infrastructure process. I couldn't confirm if upgrading fixes the problem.

My suggestion here, despite really bad, is the best answer I have for this one. Make your process create a new process that does whatever it has to do with the queue and use any form of inter process communication to get the result back. Kill this process regularly, or at every interaction with the queue.

Will make you feel bad about your own solution, but will save you a lot of e-mail traffic and frustration.